# Why is React/TS not properly recognizing my declared type? Type {} Not Assignable to Type ()=>void

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I basically have a button element pretty far down the component hierarchy so I'm passing a function from my App level downwards so that it can be called onClick within the button. I feel like I've correctly defined both the App function (newTodoCard()) as :()=>void and the prop of child component (onAddTodo()) as :()=>void. I would prefer to avoid defining an entire Interface for one function prop and want to understand why my approach isn't working.

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import TodoCard from './components/TodoCard';
import { TodoCardProps } from './components/TodoCard';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const[todoCards,setTodoCards] = useState([]);
  let currentTodoCard: TodoCardProps = {title:"",content:""};
  const newTodoCard: ()=>void = ()=>{
    currentTodoCard = {title:"NEW",content:"NEW"};
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <div className="container">
        <Sidebar {...newTodoCard}/>
        <TodoCard {...currentTodoCard}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This snippet from above is where the error is:

```
<Sidebar {...newTodoCard}/>
```

**Sidebar.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import TitleCards from './TitleCards'
import SidebarHeader from './SidebarHeader'

const Sidebar = ( onAddTodo: ()=>void) => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
        <SidebarHeader {...onAddTodo}/>
        <TitleCards/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Additionally, if I change how I pass in the prop to

```
<Sidebar onAddTodo={newTodoCard}/>
```

It seems to solve the issue, but this error Type '{ onAddTodo: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (() => void)'.
Property 'onAddTodo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (() => void)' appears (which from online research is only fixed by using {...prop} as I did originally. I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you are seeing is because you are trying to use a props spread operator `...` on something that isn't an object.  `newTodoCard` is a function.  If you want to pass it to `<SidebarHeader />` as a prop, you can just do `<SidebarHeader onAddTodo={newTodoCard} />`.

You would declare a prop in your `SidebarHeader` component to match the callback that is being passed.
The key thing to note here is that the props that are passed to your component is an object with a property called `onAddTodo`.

```
interface MyProps {
    onAddTodo: () => void;
}

export function SidebarHeader = (props: MyProps) => {

    return <div>
        <Button onClick={event => props.onAddTodo()} />
    </div>
}
```

However, your callback isn't going to work as expected the way you have written it.  When it is called, it is going to set the value of `currentTodoCard`, but that is a local variable that has a limited scope.  The next time your app re-renders, the `App` function is going to be called again, and you will get a new instance of `currentTodoCard`.  In order for your callback to work as expected, it is going to need to call `setTodoCards` or set some other state.

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate you pointing out that that var will be reset and I need to manage some state. Also thanks for pointing out that I can't use spread here, but when I try the alternative of `<SidebarHeader myCallback={newTodoCard} />` I get this error in both App.tsx and Sidebar.tsx: **Type '{ onAddTodo: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (() => void)'.
  Property 'onAddTodo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (() => void)'.**

Comment: That error is because the type annotation on your sidebar props is not right.  You will actually be passed an object with the onAddTodo method, not the method directly.

Comment: You can do something like this:
```tsx
const Sidebar = ( props: { onAddTodo: ()=>void }) => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
        <SidebarHeader {...props}/>
        <TitleCards/>
    </div>
  )
}
```
Now the props spread operator is allowed since `props` is an object.

Comment: Wow. Fixed everything. Did both the interface method you showed above and this spread one and they do the trick. One final question: is it ever possible to purely pass a method or is always passed as like the object? I really appreciate all the help Matt!

Comment: React props should always be objects, but there are some things you can do to make that easier to deal with.  For example, you can use destructuring to grab properties out of the props object with very little code.

`const Sidebar = ({ onAddTodo }: MyProps) => {  return <Button onClick={onAddTodo} /> }`

Comment: Another thing to consider looking into is to make a React Context to pass your callback down.  Instead of passing your callback as a prop through the layers in your app, you would give your callback to a Provider.  You would then have access to your callback using the corresponding Consumer.  This can be a powerful pattern, but is a bit more complicated to implement.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I will look into Context because it feels weird to keep like passing the same prop through a bunch of intermediary children that don't really use it and just pass it. I'm brand new to frontend and React/TS so thanks again, Matt!